# Simulate Validation of viewstate MAC failed at home

Tags: asp.net

In my webSite , if i do postback after 5 minuts I get this error:
Validation of viewstate MAC failed...

I realized it was probably because it's idle-timeout of the application pool
My site sits on plesk server.
My site is not use server farm, just one server.
I try to simulate the error on my computer and I can not.
I have windows 7 with iis7, i changed the application pool idle timeout to 1 minute
and submit a postback after 2 minute, but i did not get any error, the page refresh ok.
and it is the same page like i have in the real server.

so, how can I Simulate that error at home on my pc?

thx

micha

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, try adding the following:

```
<system.web>
    <pages enableViewStateMac="false" />
</system.web>
```